# .NET Button event stopped firing

Tags: asp.net, button, click

I have this page that queries a Lucene index and displays results. The querying and displaying of results happens on the page load. The button only redirects to a new page with appropriate queries. But for some reason this buttonclick event has stopped firing. I haven't changed anything obvious in the properties or the code behind functions. I tried to change it to a regular Button to get it to work but that isn't working either.

When I click the button it does seem to be doing a post back but when I put a break point on it the debugger never hits the function for the click event.

Here is the code that is not firing:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="button red submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>
```

The code behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Response.Redirect("/search.aspx?query=" + query);
}
```

Comment: I added the two lines of code and also have corrected some parts of the question. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: How does your page_load method look like? Can you hit a breakpoint if you put it in page_load?

Comment: Yes I can hit the page_load event in the page. The code that loads results on page load also works.

Comment: AutoEventWireup is set to true so I don't see a problem there.

Comment: So, can you show the page_load code then? And also, have you tried to set a breakpoint in the PreRender event as well, does it hit?

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information to solve the problem, but try to remove CssClass, try to create new empty page and put button with same code. Do not waste your time.